# How Html works to create a jLable in java

Tags: java

Since it is an array it repeats till the end of the loop. But Room 1 should not be repeated . it should be place at the top

```
first[ind] = new JLabel("<html>"
                        + "<body>"
                        + "<div id=r12style=border: 3px solid orange; margin-bottom: 5px;>"
                        + " <h2>"
                        + "   Room 1"
                        + " </h2>"
                        + "<img src=" + icon + " width=\"95\" height=\"105\"></img>"
                        + "</div>"
                        + "</body>"
                        + "</html>");
```

Comment: Remember, Java/Swing only has a limited support for CSS and supports only HTML 3.2

Comment: can i able to get this.......<div id="r12" style="border: 3px solid orange; margin-bottom: 5px;">

    <h2>

        Room 1

    </h2>
    <div id="roomDescr12" class="pictures contentColPic" align="left">
        <div id="screenThumb" style="width: 389px;"> <img width="60" height="77" alt="" src="images/icon-patient.png"></img>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: please try asking real questions, asking "can i able to get this " is so unclear we cannot help you

Comment: You can use an extra DIV in HTML for an HTML aware Swing component just as you might use it in HTML for a web page.  Get it working (and validated) first as HTML 3.2, and it should be copy/paste/fine for Java.  Also, please don't put code or HTML snippets in comments where it is unreadable, instead [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28555633/edit).

Comment: Also remember, you'll need to supply the CSS for each `<html>` block, Swing doesn't remember it across different instances

Comment: Why not you use JavaFX? it is an amazing framework you will love it :-)

Comment: In the included snippet of HTML (now edited into the question), I notice 3 `<div..` open tags and only 2 `</div..` close tags.  Does it even work in a browser the way you expect?

Comment: Nice edit @Muhammad.  :)  I had not realized that the 'code snippets' ability could deal with HTML fragments.  I hot-linked an image from [Example images for code and mark-up Q&As](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556).

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I haven't tested it):

```
IMM[ind] = new JLabel("<html><style >#aa {margin-left:25px;}</style>"
                + "<div id=\"aa\"></font><font color=\"rgb(0,0,0)\"size=\"5\">" 
                + bed_no + "<font color=\"rgb(255, 204, 204, 150)\"size=\"1\">.</div></font></html>"
                 , "<html><img src=" + icon + "></html>", JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

If you want the text under the icon:

```
IMM[ind].setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
IMM[ind].setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
```

Edit - It's probably a good idea to break up the JLabel text by using a String variable. Because it looks almost unreadable.

Comment: , "<html><img src=" + icon + "></html>", JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT); this part is not working

Comment: *"this part is not working"* What exactly do you mean by 'not working'?  Is the image loaded?  Note that is invalid HTML. The `img` element requires both `width` and `height` to be defined.

Comment: (Again) **[edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7069632)** with this new information..  But for better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  ..I am hovering as to whether to supply the 5th and last 'close vote' to this question.  Ignoring advice offered is making me think it should be closed..